# Android: chekbox in Google Maps mark and unmark markers

Tags: android, google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-markers

Is there any possibility to delete certain Google Map markers and having to do map.clear ()? Because in my app I have several checkbox marking and unmarked some markers ...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this GoogleMapsv2?

Comment: yes. it is google maps v2

Comment: when u checks checkboxe at that time save that marker instance and at last delete all saved marker by using marker.remove();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar thing in the past.

The trick is to maintain a list of the `Marker` objects, but within your own custom class (I have created a class called `MapPoint` which has the latlng, title, icon, snippet and holds a `Marker`).

Then when you want to push an update to the map you create a list of `MapPoint` objects (with the `Marker` set to null) with the current list of active `MapPoint` objects, remove duplicates and empty ones that no longer exist. This allows you to update the map as little as possible, rather than doing an entire refresh of everything.

Code snippet with comments for easier reading:

```
// holds the current list of MapPoint objects 
public ArrayList<MapPoint> mCurrentPoints = new ArrayList<MapPoint>();

public void addMapPoints(ArrayList<MapPoint> mapPoints) {
    // only process if we have an valid list
    if (mapPoints.size() > 0) {
        // iterate backwards as we may need to remove entries
        for (int i = mCurrentPoints.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // get the MapPoint at this position
            final MapPoint point = mCurrentPoints.get(i);
            // check if this point exists in the new list
            if (!mapPoints.contains(point)) {
                // if it doesn't exist and has a marker (null check), remove
                if (point.mMarker != null) {
                    // removes Marker from mMap
                    point.mMarker.remove();
                }
                // remove our MapPoint from the current list
                mCurrentPoints.remove(i);
            } else {
                // already exists, remove from the new list
                mapPoints.remove(point);
            }
        }
        // add all the remaining new points to the current list
        mCurrentPoints.addAll(mapPoints);

        // go through every current point. If no mMarker, create one
        for (MapPoint mapPoint : mCurrentPoints) {
            if (mapPoint.mMarker == null) {
                // create Marker object via mMap, save it to mapPoint
                mapPoint.mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(mapPoint.getLatLng())
                    .title(mapPoint.getTitle())
                    .icon(mapPoint.getMarker())
                    .snippet(mapPoint.getInfoSnippetText()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you will want a method that determines what `Marker` objects are to be shown, create a `MapPoint` objects for them, then send the list of them to this `addMapPoints()` method.

A couple of good ideas: `synchronize` on the `mCurrentPoints` list (removed to make code snippet simpler) and ensuring you **run on UI thread** for the adding/removing markers. (Good idea to do this processing off the main thread then hop on to it for the actual adding/removing of `Markers`). And adapt to your own situation of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setVisible(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) on a [`Marker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) object (not a [`MarkerOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html), this is important). Add all the markers you want as visible/invisible, keep the references to the `Marker` objects, and toggle them on demand.